# Twitter4j API track and location filter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'am using Twitter4j API to collect tweets from india. I am applying filter to collect tweets having specific keywords only, but i'am getting all tweets from india region, not having that specific keywords. my code is

```
    FilterQuery filter = new FilterQuery();
    String keyword[]= {"flu"};

    double [][]location ={{68.1,8.06},{97.41,37.10}};

    filter.track(keyword);

    filter.locations(location);

    twitterstream.addListener(listener);

    twitterstream.filter(filter);
```

how can get tweets from India having "flu" as a part of tweet text.

Answer (score 1):

This is so because twitter filter parameters together do not apply as AND but OR.
Check more here - https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters

The twitter API documentation also says so -

`Bounding boxes do not act as filters for other filter parameters. For example` `track=twitter&locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8 would match any tweets containing the term Twitter` `(even non-geo tweets) OR coming from the San Francisco area.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, so how can i solve my problem, means filter specific keyword tweets from specific location.

Comment: May be you can collect tweets on location and provide a filter logic of your own or collect keyword specific tweets and identify geographic distribution.